# JAXB List as top level XML

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs

**UPDATE:** Ultimately I tried everything suggested here and seemed to have some progress but my API was over engineered for the intended purpose and I ran out of time, so I switched to hard coding "student-list" in the string response of my GET /student call which was more than enough for the proof of concept I needed it for.

I am working on a simple REST service that uses XML to work with student records.

when I do a GET on /student I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<students>
    <student>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <name>Jane</name>
    </student>
    ...
</students>
```

However, I would like the output to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-list>
    <student>
        <grade>B</grade>
        <name>Jane</name>
    </student>
    ...
</student-list>
```

Here is my **Student.java** snippet:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String grade;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String grade) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    // getters/setters ...

}
```

I have tried change the XmlRootElement to be "student-list", but that makes every sub element of the list a student-list type, and ignores the top level element list.

The project uses JAX-RS with a StudentsResource class which I have tried setting the XmlRootElement name on that resource class, but that did not affect any output.

It seems to be automatically naming the top level list based on the StudentsResource class, and I cannot figure out how to override this name.

I have been combing the documentation on this but Java is not my strongest language these days so I am having trouble understanding how the pieces fit together for JAXB and JAX-RS.

Any ideas, or a push in the right direction ?

**EDIT: added StudentsResource.java snippet:**

```
@Path("/student")
public class StudentsResource {
    // this is a mapper class
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    StudentService studentService;

    public StudentsResource() {
        studentService = new StudentService();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml;charset=utf-8")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentService.getStudentAsList();
    }
    ...        
}
```

Based on Mateen Momin's feedback, I now have this outputting by the REST service on GET /student:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<studentDao_Students>
    <student>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <grade>B</grade>
    </student>
    ...
</studentDao_Students>
```

I have a StudentDao, which gets wrapped by a StudentService, which ultimately gets called by resource classes to make the HTTP calls possible.  I have moved my student class into StudentDao, which made me realize that the StudentService is what is actually getting marshalled, here are updated snippets:

**StudentDao.java**:

```
public enum StudentDao {
    instance;
    private Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();

    private StudentDao() {

        //pre-populate for testing purposes
        Student student = new Student("John", "A");
        students.put("John", student);
        student = new Student("Jane", "B");
        students.put("Jane", student);
        student = new Student("TESTUSER", "F");
        students.put("TESTUSER", student);
    }

    public Map<String, Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name="student")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Student {
        private String name;
        private String grade;

        public Student() {
        }

        public Student(String name, String grade) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.grade = grade;
        }
        // getters/setters here...
    }
}
```

**StudentService.java**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StudentService {

    StudentDao studentDao;

    public StudentService() {
        studentDao = StudentDao.instance;
    }
    // CRUD methods here which call the StudentDao HashMap
}
```

**StudentsResource.java**:

```
@Path("/student")
public class StudentsResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    StudentService studentService;

    public StudentsResource() {
        studentService = new StudentService();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml;charset=utf-8")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentService.getStudentAsList();
    }

    // other HTTP calls, POST,PUT,etc. here        
}
```

I created a main function to see what happens if I specify the JAXBContext:

**main for testing console output**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentService studentDao = new StudentService();        

        StudentDao.Student stu1 = new StudentDao.Student();
        stu1.setName("marc");
        stu1.setGrade("A");
        StudentDao.Student stu2 = new StudentDao.Student();
        stu2.setName("jacob");
        stu2.setGrade("B");
        StudentDao.Student stu3 = new StudentDao.Student();
        stu3.setName("anthony");
        stu3.setGrade("A");

        studentDao.createStudent(stu1);
        studentDao.createStudent(stu2);
        studentDao.createStudent(stu3);


        try {

            File file = new File("out.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(StudentService.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(studentDao, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(studentDao, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this main function to see the output I actually get this, which does NOT match the REST output of course:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-list>
    <studentDao>instance</studentDao>
</student-list>
```

Which seems promising, but I cannot get seem to get the top level class name to be overridden in the REST calls, which is ultimately what I need.

Any other ideas of what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: can you show your `StudentsResource` or maybe just relevant part

Comment: Without having to write any custom serialization components, any support for this will be implementation specific. I know RESTEasy has support for this. From what I remember checking before, I don't think Jersey has this capability. What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: Did you use `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "student-list")` ?

Comment: @MateenMomin I will give that a shot later today and reply back.  I have also added a portion of StudentsResource.java which has a getStudents() method which utilizes a studentService.

Comment: @peeskillet I am using: JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01

Answer (score 1):

*Students class*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "student-list")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Students{
//students
    @XmlElement(name = "student")
    public ArrayList<Student> studentsLst;

    //getters and setters
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsLst() {
        return studentsLst;
    }

    public void setStudentsLst(ArrayList<Student> studentsLst) {
        this.studentsLst = studentsLst;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Student {
        private String name;
        private String grade;

        public Student() {
        }

        public Student(String name, String grade) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.grade = grade;
        }

        // getters/setters ...
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }

        public void setGrade(String grade) {
            this.grade = grade;
        }

    }

}
```

*main method* /marshaller use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Students.Student stu1 = new Students.Student();
        stu1.setName("marc");
        stu1.setGrade("A");
        Students.Student stu2 = new Students.Student();
        stu2.setName("jacob");
        stu2.setGrade("B");
        Students.Student stu3 = new Students.Student();
        stu3.setName("anthony");
        stu3.setGrade("A");

        ArrayList<Students.Student> studentsLst = new ArrayList<>();
        studentsLst.add(stu1);
        studentsLst.add(stu2);
        studentsLst.add(stu3);

        Students students = new Students();

        students.setStudentsLst(studentsLst);


        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, System.out);

              } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
              }
}
```

*output generated:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-list>
    <student>
        <name>marc</name>
        <grade>A</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>jacob</name>
        <grade>B</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>anthony</name>
        <grade>A</grade>
    </student>
</student-list>
```

PS: Since you are using REST, the *main method* given above can be used for your FYI. Use this *main method* to build your `studentService.getStudentAsList()` method accordingly. (My assumption is that it shall pretty much give the same xml.) :)

Comment: I will give this a shot later on today or tomorrow.  Would this solution give the same results if my Student class is not a sub class?  I think I have a couple layers of abstraction I am struggling with.  I have a Student class which gets handled within the StudentDao which gets called by the StudentService which gets called by the StudentsResource.  In this scenario it seems my StudentDao is very similar to what your Students class above is doing, but I haven't had much luck putting the JAXB annotations on the Dao.  I haven't tried as you suggested though.  I will try it out and report back!

Comment: What the implementation basically does is create an inner class `Student`. You can use this inner class in your studentDao by referring it as `Students.Student` Whenever you want a jaxb xml this outer `Student` class will serve as a marshall object. Do try and update, Happy to help :)

Comment: I was able to get a change ... not the right one though, I will update my original post with the new outcome.  Again, there are several abstraction layers at play here.